# Parametric optimization in Python

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have the following function which I wish to maximize:

[image: 1]

where each [image: 2] is a given number, and each [image: 3] and [image: \sqrt{foo}] is a parameter constrained by [image: 4].

How can I solve this using Python?

I have tried the following using Scipy:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective_function(params, X):
    theta, phi = params[:len(X)], params[len(X):]
    return - np.sum(np.log(1 + X * theta.reshape(-1, 1) * phi.reshape(1, -1)))

def constraint(params):
    return np.concatenate((1 - params, params))


N, M = A.shape

# Initial guess for parameters
initial_guess = np.ones(N + M)

# Define the bounds for the parameters
bounds = [(0, 1)] * (N + M)

# Define the constraints
constraints = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint}]

# Solve the optimization problem
result = minimize(objective_function, initial_guess, args=(A,), bounds=bounds, constraints=constraints)
```

However, this code has been running for hours, and I am not sure how long I can expect it to take, or if it will not converge.

I suppose the problem is that, in my case, N=3000 and M=70, which makes it a rather complex optimisation problem. Are there more suitable libraries than Scipy for this?

Update:

My matrix A has shape (N, M) = (3000, 70) and contains the values -1 (6%), 0 (71%), and 1 (23%). The values are rather randomly distributed in the matrix.

For further explanation of the data and the context, please see the following [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/616382/ranking-of-multiple-raters-with-partially-overlapping-assessments).

Comment: do you have a test dataset or something?

Comment: @UlisesBussi I do have, but I am not sure how to best add the data to the question, given that the array is a bit too large to past in the question (shape (3000, 70)).

Comment: `def constraint(params):` Can you explain this intended purpose of this constraint? I don't see how it corresponds to the problem. The bounds are already enforcing the constraint that all parameters are between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Reinderien No, theta and phi are continuous and constrained to be between zero and 0. If they where binary, the notation would have been {0, 1} instead of (0, 1).

Comment: @NickODell Good point! Do you know if it is better to remove the constraints or the bounds?

Comment: @NickODell I wanted to avoid the values getting too close to 0 or 1.

Comment: @Filip I can think of a couple of ideas for how to prevent that. 1) Change the bounds from (0, 1) to (0.1, 0.9). 2) Add a penalty to the objective function for values too close to the bounds. e.g. `return - np.sum(np.log(1 + X * theta.reshape(-1, 1) * phi.reshape(1, -1))) + b * np.sum(np.abs(X - 0.5))` where `b` is some arbitrary constant that controls the strength of this penalty. 3) Same as (2), but using squaring instead of `np.abs()`. Makes the penalty increase faster the further you move from 0.5.

Comment: Generally for large datasets they need to link to an external source; but at the least - please provide the valid range and typical distribution of A.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function has an easily-defined analytic Jacobian, that's definitely the first thing to add.

```py
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import check_grad, minimize, Bounds


def objective_function(params: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray) -> float:
    theta, phi = params[:len(X), np.newaxis], params[len(X):]
    return -np.log(1 + X * phi * theta).sum()


def jacobian(params: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    theta, phi = params[:len(X), np.newaxis], params[len(X):]
    df_dtheta = -(1/(theta + 1/(X * phi))).sum(axis=1)
    df_dphi = -(1/(phi + 1/(X * theta))).sum(axis=0)

    return np.hstack((df_dtheta, df_dphi))


def run() -> None:
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)
    A = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(100, 20))  # 3000x70
    N, M = A.shape

    for _ in range(10):
        params = rand.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=N + M)
        err = check_grad(objective_function, jacobian, params, A)
        assert err < 1e-5

    result = None
    def solve() -> object:
        nonlocal result
        result = minimize(
            fun=objective_function,
            jac=jacobian,
            x0=np.full(shape=N + M, fill_value=0.5),
            args=(A,),
            bounds=Bounds(lb=0, ub=1),
            options={
                'maxiter': 20_000,
            },
        )
    print(timeit(solve, number=1))
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Without the Jacobian, on a reduced problem size of 100x20, I get

```
0.29418089998944197
  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: -51.10172933377105
        x: [ 3.497e-01  1.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00  1.090e-01]
      nit: 21
      jac: [ 9.878e-02 -1.207e+00 ... -2.288e+00  8.949e-02]
     nfev: 2904
     njev: 24
 hess_inv: <120x120 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

With the Jacobian, I get

```
0.009943499986547977
  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
  success: True
   status: 0
      fun: -51.101729432196976
        x: [ 3.497e-01  1.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00  1.090e-01]
      nit: 21
      jac: [ 9.878e-02 -1.207e+00 ... -2.288e+00  8.949e-02]
     nfev: 24
     njev: 24
 hess_inv: <120x120 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

That's a 29.6x speedup; nothing to sneeze at.

There might not be much more you can do within scipy. If you're desperate, then drop down to C and/or use GPGPU computation, or use professional optimisation software.

Comment: The problem dimension is N=3000 and M=70, so with Gradient descent (GD) it will  soon  be trapped in a local minima.

Comment: @gdlmx [minimize is a local minimizer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#local-multivariate-optimization); if the OP were so concerned about global optimization they would have presumably used something else. Crucially, the Jacobian is evaluated _whether we give it or not_; see `njev: 24` in case 1 - it's just done numerically which is much more inefficient.

Comment: @Reinderien I am concerned about global optimization. And maybe I should have used something else. Maybe you could point me to something?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion to take advantage of the specific math structure of your object function, which can be rewritten to

[image]

Note that inside the square brackets there is a polynomial of ϕₘ. All the different ϕₘ are independent of each other. Therefore, you can optimize each one-dimensional polynomial function,

fₘ(ϕₘ) = ∏ₙ   (1+xₙₘθₙ⋅ϕₘ )  = 1 + k₁ ⋅ ϕₘ + k₂ ⋅ ϕₘ²  + … + kₙ ⋅ ϕₘᴺ

Because 0 < ϕₘ < 1 , maybe you can ignore those higher order terms and find the ϕₘ of local minima / maxima analytically as a function of xₙₘ and θₙ.

It won't solve the entire optimization problem. However, it can reduce the dimension dramatically, to 70 or 3000 (depending on solving the polynomial of ϕₘ or θₙ).

Another trick can come from the fact that 71% elements in the matrix xₙₘ are zero, so you have a very sparse matrix of polynomial coefficients.

### Option2

The approximation

log (1+xₙₘθₙ⋅ϕₘ ) ≈ xₙₘθₙ⋅ϕₘ

could be valid if |xₙₘθₙ⋅ϕₘ| << 1

Since ∑xₙₘ⋅θₙ⋅ϕₘ is basically an inner product of two vectors {θₙ} and {ϕₘ}, you can easily solve it with linear- and quadratic-programming (LP & QP) libraries like [gurobi](https://www.gurobi.com/resources/linear-programming-lp-a-primer-on-the-basics/).
Maybe the condition |xₙₘθₙ⋅ϕₘ| << 1  is satisfied in that solution. Then you get a shortcut to the final answer.